# Android Remove SeekBar Background

Tags: java, android, seekbar

Is there a way I can remove the background bar image in the SeekBar android widget?

I just want it to show a slider with no progress bar behind it.

[image: Remove this]

Any help?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Well I solved my own problem.

To remove the background, you have to create a blank drawable and set it to the progressDrawable:

```
satBar.setProgressDrawable(invisibleBackground);
```

Setting it to null doesn't seem to work.

Answer (score 39):

There is a simpler way that doesn't require creating a new drawable.
Simply set the following in your xml definition

```
android:progressDrawable="@android:color/transparent"
```

Or if you want to do it in your code:

```
mySlider.setProgressDrawable(new ColorDrawable(android.R.color.transparent));
```

Comment: Better solution than @GuyNoir 's solution above which requires an artificial "invisible drawable" to be created

Comment: Just a note: you can't use #0000, but using @android:color/transparent works.

Comment: But this removes the horizontal line also on holo light theme. I would like to keep that.

Comment: @lalitm I'm not sure what you mean. The OP wants to remove the bar and keep only the tab. Isn't the horizontal line the equivalent of the bar in holo light? I guess the best thing to do would be to post a new question and include an image of what you want to do. Or maybe the answer from CommonsWare below is what you want to do?

Answer (score 3):

Have you tried [`setBackgroundDrawable(null)`](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/view/View.html#setBackgroundDrawable(android.graphics.drawable.Drawable))?

Comment: I have. The background drawable is actually behind the bar itself. I need a way to delete the bar (and also change the image of the slider)

Comment: and how I can restored to the initial after that ? tks

Comment: @Paul: Try calling `getBackground()` first, saving the result somewhere, and later restoring it via `setBackgroundDrawable()`. Despite the non-parallel names, `getBackground()` returns a `Drawable`.

Comment: unfortunately didn't worked... I've posted a clear question related to this issue here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14054548/seekbar-programatically-change-indeterminate-mode thanks.

Answer (score 2):

One way to do this would be to change the color of the progress bar to the background color. You have to use a custom layout.

```
<SeekBar
  android:layout_width="350px"
  android:layout_height="25px"
  android:layout_margin="30px"
  android:layout_x="60px"
  android:layout_y="185px"
  android:id="@+id/seekbar"
  android:progressDrawable="@drawable/myprogress"
/>
```

A custom layout is given below - play around with the colors :

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<layer-list xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">

<item android:id="@android:id/background">
<shape>
    <corners android:radius="5dip" />
    <gradient
            android:startColor="#ff9d9e9d"
            android:centerColor="#ff5a5d5a"
            android:centerY="0.75"
            android:endColor="#ff747674"
            android:angle="270"
    />
</shape>
</item>


<item
android:id="@android:id/progress"
>
<clip>
    <shape>
        <corners
            android:radius="5dip" />
        <gradient
            android:startColor="#9191FE"
            android:centerColor="#9191FE"
            android:centerY="0.75"
            android:endColor="#9191FE"
            android:angle="270" />
    </shape>
</clip>
</item>
```

Answer (score 0):

create an xml file `seekbar_progress.xml` and place it in `drawable` folder.Here stripes is an image,take an image and place it in `drawable` folder.

**seekbar_progress.xml**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<layer-list xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android" >  

  <item>
    <clip>
    <bitmap xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
        android:src="@drawable/stripes"
        android:tileMode="repeat"
        android:antialias="true"
        android:dither="true"
        android:filter="false"
        android:gravity="left"
    />
    </clip>
</item>
</layer-list>
```

Now in your `main xml` file that is having seekbar code, take an image and store in `drawable` folder.here seekbar is an image.

```
    <SeekBar
             android:id="@+id/seekbar"
             android:layout_width="wrap_content"
             android:layout_height="wrap_content"
             android:background="@drawable/seekbar"
             android:progressDrawable="@drawable/seekbar_progress"/>
```