# Show transparent activity on seekbar change

Tags: android, android-animation, android-manifest, android-linearlayout, transparency

When we change brightness, its activity become transparent
So We can see the home screen/ another app that running behind. I want **(100% same like Brightness seekbar)** on my custom seekbar.

[image]

My App main activity background color is gray,

I want when seekbar drag: My activity becomes transparent and show background activities/Background Home screen,

When drag completes its back to normal on gray background.

**My Research:**

I search on transparent activities, I found many questions and many different styles and theme options.

Here is my last try:

```
<activity android:name=".Activity" 
     android:theme="@android:style/Theme.Translucent">
```

Every time when I follow StackOverflow answers, I get this error:

> "You need to use a Theme.AppCompat theme (or descendant) with this
>   activity."

=>I also try, Transparent background color, Transparent drawable, transparent from manifest,

**Result**: Background show white, not transparent

I have just 1 main activity, with custom brightness seekbar and other options.

My Manifest file

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
package="st.package">

<uses-permission 
android:name="android.permission.ACTION_MANAGE_OVERLAY_PERMISSION"/>
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.SYSTEM_ALERT_WINDOW" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WRITE_SETTINGS" />

<application
    android:allowBackup="true"
    android:icon="@mipmap/ic_launcher"
    android:label="@string/app_name"
    android:supportsRtl="true"
    android:theme="@style/AppTheme">
    <activity android:name=".MainActivity"
        android:theme="@android:style/Theme.Translucent">
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />
            <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
        </intent-filter>
    </activity>


    <service android:name="st.package.ChatHeadService"
        android:exported="true">
    </service>

    <receiver android:name="MainActivity$switchButtonListener" />
</application>
```

MainActivity.xml

```
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
tools:context="overlayhead.overlayhead.MainActivity"
android:orientation="vertical"
android:windowIsTranslucent="true"
android:id="@+id/LinearLayout"
android:background="@android:color/transparent"
>
```

Comment: see this link and take idea what ever u want. 1)[remove background of seekbar](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2459326/android-remove-seekbar-background) 2)[transparent seek bar](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26989400/custom-seekbar-thumb-not-transparent-on-lollipop-api21)

Comment: see this link and take idea what ever u want. 1)[remove background of seekbar](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2459326/android-remove-seekbar-background) 2)[transparent seek bar](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26989400/custom-seekbar-thumb-not-transparent-on-lollipop-api21)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> "You need to use a Theme.AppCompat theme (or descendant) with this activity."

It is because you need to use an AppCompat Theme. So you can define a custom theme in your styles.xml and use it as the theme for your desired `Activity`.

```
<style name="Theme.AppCompat.Translucent" parent="Theme.AppCompat.NoActionBar">
        <item name="android:windowNoTitle">true</item>
        <item name="android:windowBackground">@android:color/transparent</item>
        <item name="android:colorBackgroundCacheHint">@null</item>
        <item name="android:windowIsTranslucent">true</item>
        <item name="android:windowAnimationStyle">@android:style/Animation</item>
    </style>
```

in your manifest file, declare `Theme.AppCompat.Translucent` as your theme

```
<activity android:name=".MainActivity"
        android:theme="@style/Theme.AppCompat.Translucent">
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />
            <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
        </intent-filter>
    </activity>
```

Comment: I just add your style in my style.xml, in manifest activity android:theme="@android:style/Theme.Translucent" ---- still return same error... 
Please check question, i add my complete manifest file

Comment: @AsadRaza in your manifest, you need to use Theme.AppCompat.Translucent. see my edit

Comment: Like this? android:theme="@android:style/Theme.AppCompat.Translucent"   ---- Its return error.  "cannot resolved", your code in resource/values/style.xml

Comment: nop, you don't need  the android prefix since this is a custom theme, see my edited answer please

Comment: Love you.. thank you :) , Now tell me please, How can i change activity transparent and solid color at run time, from java code...

Comment: now your activity is transperent, right? so you can  change the baground of your parent FrameLayout in your Activity layout file at runtime to get your desired output. view.setBackground may be helpfull

Answer (score 1):

for color transparency you should provide color code with 8 digits where first two digits just after # represent transparency in percentage so if you want white color with 50% transparency then you should write color value as "#50ffffff".

by using this technique in java you can do like this

```
yourLayout.setBackgroundColor(Color.parseColor("#"+i+"bdbdbd"));
```

where i will be from 00 to 99 as per value of i color transparency will be changed. so as per seekbar value increase and decrease value of i from 00 to 99.

Comment: I use your code in onCreate(), its change my activity background color lite and dark, not transparent. :(

Comment: what is your actual layout background color and what color you are using to transparent? can you show me that sample?

Comment: try by putting a temporary textview in relative layout and check again it will disappear when transparency is less.

Comment: if it is really helpful then approve my answer.

Comment: I remove all styles from activity to test your code... I test with "#"+20+"000000" ...... "#"+50+"000000" ..... "#"+80+"000000", Result is just gray and dark gray, not transparent

Comment: try this "#"+00+"000000" by putting 00 transparency and 000000 is black color code so your layout behine that may be white so it look like gray. so it may be happening because I tried that try changing different color. you can see this in many tutorials also.

Comment: Thank you, i use your code to improve @darish answer... +1 Vote,, now i can do transparent and solid color at run time...